# How to move from 1.5 to 1.7 of django eclipse project?

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I am developing django project on Eclipse pydev project. And thinking bout upgrading django 1.5
to 1.7 version due to migration operation. Should I have to make a new project and configure and manually copy the files and past it? Or is there anyway efficient way?

Comment: Django 1.7, if I'm not mistaken, already uses python 3, so there might be changes in some of the files you'll have to make, beyond that, I think only upgrading the version of Django you have installed in your machine should do the trick.

Comment: [Differences between Python 2 and Python 3](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/key_differences_between_python_2_and_3.ipynb)

Comment: @t.pimentel then i just rewrite the version at app.yaml 1.5 to 1.7, and it will work right? I read the guideline and it says that python 2.7 is also available for django 1.7

Comment: Take a look at [Upgrading Django to a newer version](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/upgrade-version.html), but I think there shouldn't be any problems (never done it, just guessing!).